# Fuzzy finder script to search file contents while floating (i.e. in dmenu/rofi style)

Tags: linux, bash, vim, zsh

I've been trying to create a script with the following functionality: I push a button in my window manager -> a fuzzy finder menu in floating mode pops up where I can type a keyword to search the content for any text file (which includes a preview pane) -> after finding the correct file I hit enter, the file opens in vim in a new window, and the floating fuzzy finder terminal exits.

To achieve this, I tried combining two existing scripts

- https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/examples#searching-file-contents (the last script called "ff")
- https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/examples#fzf-as-dmenu-replacement

However, I don't seem to be able to get it right, due to a lack of programming experience. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you could share how far you've gotten and how it does not work?

I wrote two scripts where one indexes my text files and then another lets me search them for editing in vim with fzf - but it's not based on file contents (which I'd use rg/grep for as your first link suggests too).

For the window manager I'd look at how to make a scratchpad in it for the floating window part.